# xml image in android studio

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout

i am trying to make an app for android i want to put an image in my code but it don't want to show it

this is my code

```
ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/BTA-pro"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**and what the programma said to me is** 
The following classes could not be instantiated:

> - android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom
>   views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this
>   is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then
>   manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details
>   java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   android.content.res.Resources_Delegate.getValue(Resources_Delegate.java:747)
>     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1286)   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getValue(ResourcesWrapper.java:204)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.createDrawableIfNeeded(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:231)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:50)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:63)
>     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) Copy
>   stack to clipboard   Failed to convert @drawable/BTA-pro into a
>   drawable (Details) (4 similar errors not shown)  Tip: Try to refresh
>   the layout.

Comment: post your full xml code

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/BTA-pro"
```

to:

```
android:src="@drawable/BTA-pro"
```

Comment: do you mean android:src="@drawable/BTA-pro" because i putted you code in my programma and it give al faults

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of your image. In android studio, using dash('-') is invalid while naming the file.
BTA-pro => BTA_pro